# How to get email body using the Robot Framework?

Tags: email, robotframework

How can I get an email body using the Robot Framework?

I use the ImapLibrary, but get the error.

```
open mailbox  host=imap.gmail.com  user=v@j.com  password=PW
${LATEST} =  wait for email  sender=d@j.com
${body} =  get email body  ${LATEST}
```

I get the error for the last step:

> LookupError: 'quoted-printable' is not a text encoding; use codecs.decode() to handle arbitrary codecs

Comment: I don't know if this is part of the problem or not, but you probably don't need quotes around `${LATEST}`.

Comment: @BryanOakley I get the `LookupError: 'quoted-printable' is not a text encoding; use codecs.decode() to handle arbitrary codecs` error when I've removed quotes.

Comment: Even I got same issue this is due to python version. use 2.7 this works fine

Comment: I have Python 3.7.0. I understand when I should update something but I don't understand a solution (except temporary cases) when I should downgrade something.

Answer (score 1):

replace `decode('quoted-printable')` with `decode('utf-8')` in init.py of imaplibrary

Comment: You gave correct but a raw solution. I found the library which satisfies my requirement - ImapLibrary2.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the Robot Framework Library `ImapLibrary2` instead of `ImapLibrary` with this issue already fixed.

The code remains the same. But remember this will give back you body of the email along with all the `html tags`.

Here is the reference link [ImapLibrary](https://github.com/lasselindqvist/robotframework-imaplibrary2)

You can follow my detailed solution here: [Parse Email body in Robot Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66744176/15285010)